# will the left|rightfirewall option of StrongSwan open UDP 500/4500 and protocol number 50 on iptable?

Tags: networking, iptables, ipsec

I know the StrongSwan use UDP 500 and 4500 for IKE traffic and IP protocal number 50 for ESP packages.

I am not sure the usage of left|rightfirewall option(http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection) in StrongSwan, will this option open these port while the connection being enabled?

or Is there any config that open these ports automatically once the ipsec daemon(charon) is started?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will this option open these port while the connection being enabled?

No, the ports/protocols you mentioned have to be opened in the firewall before. Otherwise strongSwan cannot setup any connections in the first place. What `left|rightfirewall` does is insert forwarding rules for the traffic that is being tunneled (as specified with `left|rightsubnet` and `left|rightprotoport`).  If `lefthostaccess` is enabled INPUT and OUTPUT rules are inserted too, which allow to access the gateway on its internal address.

> Is there any config that open these ports automatically once the ipsec daemon(charon) is started?

No, you have to configure the firewall yourself.